# Apache Alias and .htacces at Zend project is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework

I made zend project and it had work correctly with out any problem. I created new virtual host with alias as follows.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/home/dinuka/workspace/peye_backend/public"
   ServerName peye.test.com

   <Directory "/home/dinuka/workspace/peye_backend/public">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

   Alias /new /home/dinuka/workspace/peye_backend_new/public
   <Directory "/home/dinuka/workspace/peye_backend_new/public">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess at /home/dinuka/workspace/peye_backend_new/public is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /new/index.php [NC,L]
```

Now `peye.test.com` and `peye.test.com/new` url is working and they redirect to different sites. But some time it redirect to  `peye.test.com/new/new`

I debug the from controller and find it is redirect from `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` class.

```
class Eme_Peye_Models_DbTable_Directorytypes extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'dir_types';
    protected $_sequence = 'dir_types_dir_type_id_seq';

    public function getAllDirectorytypes($order = 'dir_type_name')
    {
        //die('Now works')
        $select = $this->select()
                        ->from($this, array('key'=>'dir_type_id', 'value'=>'dir_type_name'))
                        ->order($order);
        //die('Not working')    

        return  $this->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
    }

}
```

I can't describe this problem another way. Please help me. I think that problem from apache.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens *sometimes*, then it must be because of some invalid URL and not because of apache configuration. Double check your urls.